# Rearranging bootstrap columns on smaller screens

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the following layout I am working with.
[image: Current Layout]

The code for it is as follows:

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col">
    A
  </div>
  <div className="col-6">
    <div className="row h-50">
      B
    </div>
    <div className="row h-50">
      C
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="col text-center my-auto">
    D
  </div>
</div>
```

I am looking to rearrange this on smaller screens to look like:
[image]

I am looked into `pull` and `push` in Bootstrap but all the examples I see involves when you just have a single row with single columns. I may be overthinking things but I can't seem to figure out what to do since B and C are nested within another row.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, given the fact that they are nested. It's rather unusual to want to stack `A` *between* B and C in a mobile layout, though this would be possible if you were to take them out of the parent. Would it be possible to give `B` and `C` independent rows?

Comment: I'm able to rewrite the code for the non mobile version... to not nest them. That's just how i have it now. I'm completely open to suggestions because my normal hack until I get something working is just not working this time.  This is the design I was given but I'm willing to go back and say it's not possible if that is the case. I know I can do this with css grid but there's been push back on using that.

Comment: I assume you are using `className` because you are working with React _ If so then tagging your question appropriately might help others in future _ #JustSaying : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible by repeating the first div 'A' and toggling the visibility on the small size `col-sm`;

Working **snippet** below:

```css
.classA {
  background: red
}

.classB {
  background: yellow
}

.classC {
  background: green
}

.classD {
  background: blue
}

div{ text-align:center; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-3  d-none d-sm-block classA">
    A (original)
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 h-50 classB">
        B
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 d-block d-sm-none classA">
        A
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 h-50 classC">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-3  classD">
    D
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed